Trouble setting up python environment
I need to use Python 3.11 or lower for a library that I need, but I don't know how to set up an environment for it.
In my terminal, tried to do
python3.11 -m venv .venv

but i get
python3.11' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Instead, i tried to just put in the path to python3.11, so I did
C:\Users\forha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv .venv

and I get this pop up:

I'm not sure how I can set up the python environment, so thanks in advance for the help.

Did you pip install virtualenv? Also if python3.11 isn't aliased you might find it as python or python3.

yeah i installed virtualenv, and when I do python it just makes me get on python 3.12.4 because thats the one I previously got. I don't want to get rid of it though, I just want to make an environment.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Both of your approaches should work-- maybe check this thread

Did you try using PyLauncher installed with Python on Windows: py -3.11 -m venv .venv or just Python: python -m venv .venv? I can't reproduce the same issue you have with Python 3.11 on Windows since you used python3.11 as a command.

When i do py -3.11 -m venv .venv, I get the error "Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\forha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv .venv2': %1 is not a valid Win32 application." I used python3.11 because i heard thats how you do it, but in all honesty i've never done something like this before, so I'll take whatever the stand method is for doing this type of stuff.

Something seems to be wrong with your installed Python runtime. Uninstall it, remove all related folder and download+install a fresh version from https://www.python.org/downloads/

If you don't have python 3.11 installed it won't create a venv. You need to get the exe for 3.11 and install that like you did for 3.12

I have it installed tho
